# Appium set Android time based on current device time

Tags: android, automation, appium, timepicker

Is there a way to set the Android time using Appium based on Androids current time?

At the moment I am "hardcoding the time" using Android locators. This will set the time picker to 3:35

get visitSetHour() { return $('//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView.RadialPickerTouchHelper[@content-desc="3"]') }
get visitSetMinutes() { return $('//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView.RadialPickerTouchHelper[@content-desc="35"]') }

visitSetHour.click();
visitSetMinutes.click();

However I wanted to do this in a more dynamic way that changes every time I run my script by using the devices time.

I can get the devices time with:

let time = driver.getDeviceTime();

My question is now how can I use that time and set the time picker to 5 minutes from that time?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Appium API exposes only the end point to get time.

You can change device time via adb: `adb shell date -s "yyyymmdd.[[[hh]mm]ss]"`

or in your test code: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell date -s \"yyyymmdd.[[[hh]mm]ss]\");`

If you want to do it in test code via driver instance, I suggest reading how to [execute adb commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) with Appium API